# Kubernetes ALB Ingres doesn't route traffic to any rules except /*

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I deployed a "monolithic" app into kubernetes on AWS. This app works fine through the ALB.

Next I want to deploy a small service at the same cluster and map traffic to it through the same ALB ingress.

Here is how the Ingress manifest looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: scala-backend-ingress
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: akka-backend
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /proxy/service/*
            backend:
              serviceName: proxy-service-np
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: akka-main-np
              servicePort: 80
```

Unfortunately when I call:

GET www.aliace.example.com/proxy/service/traffic/data

I receive back `502 Bad Gateway` response with header `Server → awselb/2.0`.

All traffic to `/*` is handled properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in kubernetes.
The application in the container was bounded to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

can you try as below

```
- path: /proxy/service/*/*
            backend:
              serviceName: proxy-service-np
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: The same happens — 502 response. I think that adding extra `/*/*` does not make any sense, sine `*` means that the rest of the URI can be whatever

Comment: you are right. just wanted to double check that issue is not with the full path. can you share the logs from ingress controller pod